# Python vs Matlab in image processing

Tags: python, matlab

I am an IT student and am doing my BE project in Image processing. Can anybody tell me, between Python and Matlab  which is a better language for Image processing.

Comment: If you expect us to spend some time to answer your question, please devote some time in framing a decent question. Please refrain from using slang acronyms like `m` `n`. Also your question is vague considering Image Processing is a Huge Subject and there are other factor's that should be considered which you didn't mention. Question's like these get down-voted and closed subsequently.

Comment: @Abhijit its nice that i can always count on stackoverflow members to be so rude and cocky

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Python for image processing but I know that MATLAB has a verbose set of tools specifically for image processing. Additionally most of the Doctorate level students at my university use MATLAB for image processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make a choice between Matlab vs Python, apart from the usability criteria you also need to consider

1. Availability and Cost.
2. Learning Curve.
3. Scope of your Project

There is one area where Matlab would excel is the Simulink which I think you would hardly require for your purpose. Python has a rich Image Processing Library and an abundant available resources which can often offset the cost associated with Matlab in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of rude to ask this type of question when it's clear you haven't done any of the leg work. Here is a small list of resources to get you started, take a look at them and decide which are most appropriate for your project. I'm sure you're already aware of the matlab image processing library and the matlab file exchange. Also take a look at the [Python Imageing Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and [ndimage from scipy](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Ndimage). Once you've taken a look at those resources, and hopefully some others, you can come back here if you have a more specific question.